# Can I specify Git URLs as dependencies in Buck?

Tags: c++, git, buck

I am using Buck to build a C++ project.

I would like to add a Git URL (e.g. `git@github.com:owner/project.git`) as a dependency so that a build can automatically pull down a library from GitHub. I took a look at [`remote_file`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/remote_file.html), but that only seems to work for HTTP, HTTPS and Maven.

Does Buck provide this functionality out-of-the-box?

If so, is it possible to specify a specific commit hash or tag?

Comment: I don't know about Buck, but specifying a certain release of the github project  which is known to work with your code which can be updated whenever you feel like it is more apropriate? Then http https will work just as you want. Otherwise any API change will break your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buck does not support remote Git URLs.

Your options are:

- Copy the code manually into your project
- Use an equivalent `.zip` URL (GitHub gives you these)
- Use submodules, such as in [this example](https://github.com/njlr/buck-cells-example)
- Use a package manager that supports Buck, such as [Buckaroo](https://buckaroo.pm)